# ASP.NET Web Forms - Getting Path to To a File From a C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating a class to log errors in a .NET Web Forms application. However, because it is a separate class, I am having a lot of problems mapping to the correct path. Ordinarily I would use ~/, or /, but this does not work. I need it so that whatever Web Forms page calls the class, the application can find the appropriate file to write to. For example, as the code stands now, I get the following error:

```
$exception  {"Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\logs\\errors.txt'."} System.Exception {System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException}
```

The class that does the logging:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;


namespace Ticket_System
{

    public static class logger
    {

   const string PATH = "logs/errors.txt";
       public static void logError(Exception ex) {
            using (StreamWriter stream = File.AppendText(PATH))
            {
                stream.Write(ex.Source + "  " + ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace + "/n/n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I, within logger.cs, be able to reliably access the file (located in sub-directory, logs), regardless of what page calls it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you trying to say that you want to use a different logs directory when called by pages at different paths, or are you saying that you always want to find a specific logs directory location regardless of which page calls your log method? Your error shows where your code is currently trying to log, but you're not very clear on where you *want* the log to be. Also, why are you not using a logging framework?

Comment: Regardless of the page that throw an error, I want it to log to the same file. I just want the log to be a simple, flat text file located in a subdirectory (called logs) of the website. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath` to get the path of your current website, or (if you know you'll always be calling this in the context of a Request) you can use  `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~")`.

However, I'd highly recommend that you use an existing logging framework rather than trying to roll your own. It'll save you a lot of headache in the long run.